# Slide Show using JS array

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image is not get loaded by this code any improvement needed?
image url is stored into array for accessing that we required something?

```
<script>
    var images = ["lap2.png", "lap1.png", "tv1.png", "tv2.png"];
    var i;

    function slides() {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById('slider').src = "" + images[i];
            }, 8000);
        }

    }
</script>
<!--HTML CODE-->
<p id="slide"><img src="lap1.png" id="slider" onload="this.onload=null; 
this.src=slides();" multiple>
</p>
```

Comment: have you tried build the relative path to it? What error do you get?

Comment: @Alex I tried to use a relative path instead of giving an array variable there direct path will work but not with variable

Comment: okay have you replaced setIntervall with setTimeout?

Comment: `multiple` on a `<img>` tag?!

Comment: @PaulRooney Ok I'll use setTimeout but, is there any error while passing the array object?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just added it for my testing purpose sorry but do not consider it I'm a beginner in javascript any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Please see [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3583724/4642212). The empty string in `"" + images[i]` serves no purpose; remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 var images = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png"];
 let i=0;
 setInterval(function() {
   i = i < images.length -1 ? i + 1 : 0; 
   document.getElementById('slide').src =  `http://placehold.it/300x150?text=${images[i]}`;
 }, 1000);
```

```html
<img id="slide" src="http://placehold.it/300x150?text=1.png"></img>
```